# I am trying to customize White Label Error page in Spring-boot

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am using spring boot 1.5.10 
I am getting error "Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. I attached picture of error

[image]

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-02-15 15:31:45.872 ERROR 6968 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.serviceimpl.ErrorJson required a bean of type 'int' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'int' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Provide some code snippet. How you are trying to achieve this.

Comment: @JaydeepPatel please check answers I provided

Answer (score 0):

@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY)
@Getter(AccessLevel.PUBLIC)

@Setter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)

@NoArgsConstructor

@Component

public class ErrorJson {

```
public Integer status;
public String error;

@JsonIgnore
public String message;
public String timeStamp;
public String trace;


public ErrorJson(int status, Map<String, Object> errorAttributes) {
    this.status = status;
    this.error = (String) errorAttributes.get("error");
    this.message = (String) errorAttributes.get("message");
    this.timeStamp = errorAttributes.get("timestamp").toString();
    this.trace = (String) errorAttributes.get("trace");
}
```

}

---

@Log

@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")

@Configuration

@ComponentScan("com")

@RestController

public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

```
private static final String PATH = "/error";

@Value("${custom-error-controller.debug}")
private boolean debug;

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}

@Autowired
private ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;

@RequestMapping(value = PATH)
ResponseEntity<ErrorJson> error(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
     return ResponseEntity.status(response.getStatus())
         .body(
             new ErrorJson(response.getStatus(), getErrorAttributes(request, debug)
         )
     );
}

@Override
public String getErrorPath(){
    return PATH;
}

private Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(HttpServletRequest request, boolean includeStackTrace) {
    RequestAttributes requestAttributes = new ServletRequestAttributes(request);
    return errorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(requestAttributes, includeStackTrace);
}
```

}

Comment: I created No args constructor
and I commented out
@noArgConstructor

problem solved

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the @Component annotation from your ErrorJson class. This annotation tells Spring to create the class as a bean, which it doesn't need to be.

Edit: Note that creating a no arguments constructor is just masking the problem as it is just allowing Spring to create the class without needing to fill out your arguments, where Spring shouldn't be getting involved with this class at all.